# How can I extend Ivan Sanchez's Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim to support 'snakepause' and 'snakeplay' events

Tags: javascript, animation, leaflet, polyline

I appreciate the work he did however, we don't have control to pause the animation and play it back. I want to extend the functionalities to support play and pause option for animating `Polyline` on leaflet. Is there any way to add pausing and playing the animation on button click ? please point in the direction. If there is better way to do this please let me know.

I have examined the code and found that animation stops when value of `_snakingVertices` variable becomes `_snakeLatLngs.length-1` but couldn't put it into use. This is a unique challenge.

The javascript code can be found here [Leaflet.SnakeAnim](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim)

Comment: He is active on stackoverflow so probably he will give you some hints on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Store the return value from the call to [`L.Util.requestAnimFrame()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#util-requestanimframe) which happens [here](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/blob/230e024877dabbc67c9e00f45723fbe274371688/L.Polyline.SnakeAnim.js#L124).

Add a new method named `snakePause` or `snakeStop` or something like that, and call [`L.Util.cancelAnimFrame`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#util-cancelanimframe) with the value stored earlier. Add sanity checks (check that there is indeed a stored value, etc) as needed.

Add another method named `snakeResume` or something like that, and call `L.Util.requestAnimFrame()` to restart the deferred calls to `this._snake()`. Add sanity checks so several calls to `snakeResume` have no ill effect (check that there is no stored return value from a previous `requestAnimFrame`, etc).

---

Pausing and resuming is a pure timers problem, and should be approached with `requestAnimFrame` and `cancelAnimFrame` alone, paying attention to any potential race conditions. There is no need at all to mess with the data, besides the strictly necessary (stored values for the deferred calls, and the stored `performance.now` value for timing the growth of the line).